# Gitlab with redmine service : connection informations

Tags: gitlab, redmine

I have a Redmine and a GitLab. I try to configure the Redmine service in Gitlab but it only asks for 3 Redmine URLs (projectURL, issueURL newIssueURL) and no login / password nor API Key.

Obviously the "Test settings" button raises an error:

> We tried to send a request to the provided URL but an error occurred "

Is it possible to use a "private" redmine with gitlab?

Comment: **Don't** provide the answer in the question area, nor mark the question as solved by altering the title. Write a proper answer and accept it instead (self-answering is [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it work by adding a missing entry to redmine host in /etc/hosts

But finally it is just a module to display a redmine link inside gitlab, not a "true integration". When you click to issues it redirect you to redmine.

That is not what I want

Comment: looking for the same thing, look at this http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit